# A strange differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

When I try to do something with the plasma equation, I stumbled up on an equations like:
$$f''+\omega^2f=\exp(i\gamma e^{i\omega_0t})$$
How can I find a particular solution for this equation?

Comment: First, the ODE needs suitable initial conditions (or boundary conditions).  Then, one can construct a Green"s Function from which the solution is simply the convolution of the Green's Function with the right-hand side "forcing" function.

Answer (score 1):

The particular solutions can be expressed on the form of integrals.

Since these integrals have no closed form with a finite number of standard functions, it is not worthwhile to type in Latex the draft below.

[image]